# Uninstall the apk from a option inside the app (React Native)

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a project that requires the customer to have the latest version installed, and  if the customer's device has a previous one a modal will appear as soon as the verification of the version is finished, if the version is not the latest one, we will tell them to download the app from the store, and as soon as he clicks the OK option in the modal we will need to uninstall the current app.
This is necessary because we are having some issues when the latest version is installed when the previous one still on the device.
How to deal with it?

Comment: I don't think you can do it. You can navigate the user to `playstore`/`appstore` to uninstall it. But you can't uninstall the app itself. Because the system can't remove files while the app is running. Better if you debug and find out what's the exact issue you are facing while updating the new version.

Comment: In Android you can call the Intent `ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE` that will show a popup to the user prompting to uninstall the app (more info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE)). This is now deprecated, the recommended way is [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller#uninstall(java.lang.String,%20android.content.IntentSender)).   In iOS you can't do this

Comment: What kind of issues occurs when update version?